# How to change the Kafka client logging levels/preferences?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, kafka-producer-api

I am using a plain Java project to run (no framework) a Kafka producer and a consumer.

I am trying to control the logs generated by the `KafkaProducer` and `KafkaConsumer` code and I cannot influence it using the `log4j.properties` configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,stdout

log4j.logger.kafka=ERROR,stdout
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig=ERROR,stdout
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser=ERROR,stdout
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator=ERROR,stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

Still I get log output like the one below, whatever settings I provide in the `log4j.properties` file:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values:
...
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values:
...
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values:
...
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=UM00160, groupId=string-group] (Re-)joining group
```

How can I control the logging of the Kafka clients library? What am I missing to link my `log4j.properties` file to the Kafka clients library logging? In order not to spam the output I have to run Maven test using: `mvn test 2> /dev/null`. Can I configure this via the `log4j.properties`.

**Context:**

I have the following relevant files:

```
── test
   ├── java
   │   └── com
   │       └── example
   │           ├── PropertyReader.java
   │           └── strings
   │               └── TestKafkaStringValues.java
   └── resources
       ├── application.properties
       └── log4j.properties
```

And I am trying to run the `TestKafkaStringValues.java` both using the Maven surefire plugin (`mvn test`) or the Eclipse JUnit plugin (equivalent to `java ...`).

For surefire I use the following configuration in the Maven `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <log4j.configuration>file:log4j.properties</log4j.configuration>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and for JUnit I use the following Java VM argument: `-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties`.

I also tried in both cases to use the absolute path to `log4j.properties`. Still not working.

You can see the complete code [here](https://github.com/gabipetrovay/avro-tests/tree/575f39c9e7751f1316ac2cdb3088220dd9528345).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in the code above was that the Maven runtime dependencies (the actual Log4j logging implementation was missing). In the pom, the `slf4j-simple` logging implementation was provided. This implementation was:

- able print the Kafka logs to stdout
- NOT able to understand the `log4j.properties` or `-Dlog4j.*` properties.

Hence, once would have to include in a Log4J implementation. Here one would have the choice for [Log4j 1.x](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) (End of life) or [Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).

With the following configuration, one should be able to have a very comprehensive/granular control over the logging (including the Kafka clients).

In the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

While the `log4j-api` and `log4j-core` are the minimum requirements you would need. In order for Log4j2 to be able to control/configure also libraries/components written on top of SLF4J (and Kafka client is such a library), you need to add the 3rd dependecy: `log4j-slf4j-impl`.

**NOTE:** Note that for libraries that use SLF4J 1.8.x and higher, you will need another version of this Log4j-SLF4J adapter. See this [for more information](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html).

Now regarding configuring the logging, [Log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) is automatically loading the configuration files it it finds them, automatically searching in [multiple locations](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

If you place the following `log4j2.properties` file in the resource classpath (in `src/java/resources/` for main code and in `src/test/resource` for test code) you will get the desired outcome:

```
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

appenders = stdout

appender.stdout.name = STDOUT
appender.stdout.type = Console
appender.stdout.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.stdout.layout.pattern =%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] [%t] %c - %m%n

loggers = kafka, kafka-consumer

logger.kafka.name = org.apache.kafka
logger.kafka.level = warn

logger.kafka-consumer.name = org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer
logger.kafka-consumer.level = info
```

In the above example, all logging is written to `stdout` and:
* the root logger is logging `info` and above
* all `org.apache.kafka`-prefixed loggers log `warn` and above
* all `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer`-prefixed loggers are logging `info` and above

Here are some extra observations when using Log4j2:

- if you want JSON or YAML configuration you need extra dependecies
- the JUnit plugin in Eclipse will silently terminate without any output if the Log4j configuration is not correct. `mvn` output will show you the error though.

Comment: There is an open PR / JIRA to move Kafka to log4j2. Logback requires less config, fwiw